# How to pick which JSON file to use from multiple API calls

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm using promise to fetch two different API calls, that both return files with similar/matching data.

I'm trying to use one of the API calls to display a couple of numbers (balance of two wallets), which worked fine when there was only one API call, I was doing it like this:

```
const rewardWallet = data.result[0];
const rewardBalance = rewardWallet.balance;
```

So, `data.result[0]` was selecting result, and then the first array (0) and then the data from 'balance'. But now that there are 2 API calls, 'result' is under '0' and I can't figure out how to select the top level.

[image: Link to results API returns]

I added the second API call like this:

```
Promise.all([
    fetch('https://api.bscscan.com/api?module=account&action=balancemulti&address=0xa3968Fba9D45D52b6b978f575934364ac2d5774c,0x121F0a592a25A52E8834C87005CbF4db000010Af&tag=latest&apikey=key'),
    fetch('https://api.bscscan.com/api?module=account&action=tokenbalance&contractaddress=0x7b50c95f065dc48a0ecf8e5f992bf9bb9f4299c5&address=0x121F0a592a25A52E8834C87005CbF4db000010Af&tag=latest&apikey=key')
]).then(function (responses) {
    return Promise.all(responses.map(function (response) {
        return response.json();
    }));
}).then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

[image]
Appreciate any help.

Comment: Unclear what you mean, "selecting" between the 2 different JSON files. Also unclear what your screenshot there is supposed to show - is that the result of one of those API calls, or both already combined somehow ..? Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @Cbroe I just updated it, hope that I managed to explain it more clearly - I'm not a JS dev, just trying to learn and hack together some API stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Promise.all` to ensure request are fired off and then work with the response after all promises have resolved. See below, I've added some mock functions that mock the API calls that will just return an object with an amount.

```
const fetchWalletOne = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve({ amount: 1 });
  });
};

const fetchWalletTwo = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve({ amount: 5 });
  });
};

async function getData() {
  const [walletOne, walletTwo] = await Promise.all([
    fetchWalletOne(),
    fetchWalletTwo()
  ]);

  console.log(walletOne, walletTwo);
  console.log(walletOne.amount + walletTwo.amount);
}

getData();
```